# Sorting an int Array using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to get familiar with Java streams and similar things around that area, but unable to sort an array of type `int`. Here is my code, which does not sort the array at all.

```
class Scratch {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int [] arr3 = { 9,21,5,8 };
       Comparator<Integer> cc = (e1,e2) -> {
            return e1.compareTo(e2);
       };
       Arrays.stream(arr3).boxed().sorted();
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a "terminal" operation to the stream to do something with the data stream For example `List<Integer> result = Arrays.stream(arr3)....collect(Collectors.toList())`. Also, you don't need the comparator as that's the default for `Integer` and you aren't using it anyway.

Comment: `arr3 = IntStream.of( arr3 ).sorted().toArray() ;`  See this run [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ZYDchA). ---> `[5, 8, 9, 21]`

Comment: If you want to sort the array in-place, using streams is a bad idea. `Arrays.sort(arr3);` is simple and clear and does the job. If you insist on using streams and a `Comparator`, use either `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, `Integer::compare` or `Comparator.comparing(e -> e)`. To unbox the stream and collect it back into `arr3`, see the answer.

Comment: Or `Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue)`.

Comment: Or nothing. You aren't using the `Comparator` at all @Anonymous

Answer (score 5):

I have observed that your code prints the reference of the unsorted array, whereas it should assign the sorted array to a new variable and print that instead. Furthermore, the comparator that you have defined is not used and is not required for the code's functionality.

The original array can't be changed Java streams. Java streams work with unchangeable data and make new ones instead of modifying the original. So, if you sort with Java streams, you need to create a new sorted array. If you want to change the original array, use the usual Arrays.sort() method to sort it.

Here are both methods fixed and working, plus more:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {
  public static int[] UNSORTED_ARR = {9, 21, 5, 8};

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    sort1();
    sort2();
    sort3();
    sort4();
    sort5();
  }

  /**
   * Sort using comparator and streams
   */
  private static void sort1() {
    System.out.println("Sort using comparator and streams");
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Integer::compareTo;
    var sortedStream = Arrays.stream(UNSORTED_ARR).boxed().sorted(comparator).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedStream));
  }

  /**
   * Sort using sorted() method and streams
   */
  private static void sort2() {
    System.out.println("Sort using sorted() method and streams");
    var sortedStream = Arrays.stream(UNSORTED_ARR).sorted().toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedStream));
  }


  /**
   * Sort using sorted() method and collect list with streams
   */
  private static void sort3() {
    System.out.println("Sort using sorted() method and collect list with streams");
    List<Integer> sortedList = Arrays.stream(UNSORTED_ARR)
        .sorted()
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sortedList);
  }

  /**
   * Sort using reverseOrder() method and streams
   */
  private static void sort4() {
    System.out.println("Reverse sort using reverseOrder() method and streams");
    int[] sortedArr = Arrays.stream(UNSORTED_ARR)
        .boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArr));
  }


  /**
   * Sort using Arrays.sort()
   * This modifies the original array and not using streams
   */
  private static void sort5() {
    System.out.println("Sort using Arrays.sort()");
    Arrays.sort(UNSORTED_ARR);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(UNSORTED_ARR));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Sort using comparator and streams
[5, 8, 9, 21]
Sort using sorted() method and streams
[5, 8, 9, 21]
Sort using sorted() method and collect list with streams
[5, 8, 9, 21]
Reverse sort using reverseOrder() method and streams
[21, 9, 8, 5]
Sort using Arrays.sort()
[5, 8, 9, 21]
```

Comment: @Holger, you are correct. The boxed() method is only necessary for methods that use a comparator. I left it in the code because it was present in the original author’s version, but I have now removed it as it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create a `Stream`, another object is created. Therefore you have to assign the result of sorted stream to a variable and transform it to a data structure like a `List`.

```java
class Scratch {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int [] arr3 = { 9, 21, 5, 8 };
       List<Integer> sorted = Arrays.stream(arr3).boxed().sorted().toList();
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));
   }
}
```

In this case it is not necessary to define a comparator because when you call `sorted` the default comparator is the comparator of the data type that is `Integer`.

```java
       Comparator<Integer> cc = (e1,e2) -> {
            return e1.compareTo(e2);
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this question you need a few steps:

1. you need to convert it to `IntStream`
2. then use the stream API `sort` function for sorting
3. convert back to the normal array

   int [] arr3 = { 9, 21, 5, 8 };
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));
   //convert this to array of stream
   IntStream intStream = Arrays.stream(arr3);
   intStream = intStream.sorted();
   //convert it to array
   arr3 = intStream.toArray();
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));

Comment: I have added more [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to your answer.